# PHP cURL not sending POST Data

Tags: php, api, curl

I am trying to send some data from my php to a rest service. It seems to make a call correctly to the API but doesnt send any post data.

The Code is :

```
<?php
    $name="abcd";
    $id="xyz";
    $service_url = 'service/url';
    $curl = curl_init($service_url);
    $curl_post_data = array(
        $name,$id);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, true);
   curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post_data);
   $curl_response = curl_exec($curl);
   curl_close($curl);
   ?>
```

I would also like to manipulate the response provided.Can someone tell what i am doing wrong here.

There is a server side validation, The code is :

```
private String validateAndGetClientName(HttpServletRequest request) throws InvalidRequestException {
    String clientName = request.getParameter("name");
    if (isEmpty(clientName)) {
        throw new InvalidRequestException("Client Name cannot be empty.");
    }
    return clientName.trim();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Paramters in http queries only make sense in an associative way, so if they are named. Change the definition of your post data to this:

```
$curl_post_data = array(
    'name' => $name,
    'id' => $id
);
```

Comment: Hey, I Tried the same but still it throws the same server side validation error ( the parameter being empty)

Comment: There is nothing I can say about that, since you did not provide any code about that. I can not know what parameters that system expects or how it tries to access it. Obviously I do not know of the expected names of the parameters really are 'name' and 'id'. Only you can tell.

Comment: As you asked , I have update my question with more code from server side.Can you help me on this

Comment: @TheCoder can you log your clientName in your c# code in console like : Console.WriteLine(clientName);. to find out which string sent to c# program?

Comment: Hm, first, make sure it really is post parameters, not get parameters that your server side code expects and tries to extract from the request structure by the code above. Then I suggest you add some logging to your servers code. I am not familiar with c#, but I am sure there is an easy way to log all request details as seen from the server side. I still don't see why the parameters should _not_ be part of the post request. An alternative to that logging would be to use a network sniffer to dump the request on a network level.